# Html dynamic table

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

hey I have a table with just one row ....
i need to have an add button in my table to add another row ,
latter when the user clicks on submit all the table data should enter into database .
I have create a single row table and it works fine for entering the data into database , can any please help me modify my code to have an add row functionality and on submit to enter the data into database . My Html and PHp file are as follows . PLEASE HELP !

```
<form   name="myForm"
        method="post" 
        action="to_db.php" 
        onSubmit="alert('YOUR REQUEST HAS BEEN RECEIVED.');" >

<TABLE BORDER=0>    
    <TR>
        <TD>Department</TD>
        <TD>
            <select name="department">
                ...
            </select>
        </TD>
        <TD>Date Submitted</TD>
        <TD><input type="date" name="bday" /></TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD>Requested by</TD>
        <TD><INPUT type=text name="reqby" /></TD>   
        <TD>priority</TD>
        <TD>
            <select name="priority">
                ...
            </select>
        </TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD>Description Of Change:</TD>
        <TD><textarea name="doc" id="doc" cols="25" rows="3"></textarea></TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD>Bussiness Impact Of Change:</TD>
        <TD> <textarea name="boc" id="doc" cols="25" rows="3"></textarea></TD>
    </TR>
</TABLE>

<table class="dynatable1">
    <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Bussiness Process Impacted</th>
                <th>Tools Used / System Impacted</th>
                <th>Bussiness Driver description</th>
                <th>Impact category</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><textarea name="v1" cols="30" row="1" id="demo3" value=""></textarea></td>
                <td><textarea name="v2" cols="50" rows="2" id="demo1" value="" /></textarea></td>
                <td><textarea name="v3" cols="50" rows="2" id="demo2" value="" /></textarea></td>
                <td>
                    <select name="v4">
                        ...
                    </select> 
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

<input name ="printbtn"  type="image" src="submit.jpg" class="submit" value="SUBMIT"  >             
</form>
```

My PHP FILE IS AS FOLLOWS :

```
$dbhandle= mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password) or die("Unable to connect to database");

$selected = mysql_select_db("form",$dbhandle) or die("could not select the database");

$val1 = $_POST['crno'];
$val2 = $_POST['department'];
$val3 = $_POST['bday'];
$val4 = $_POST['reqby'];
$val5 = $_POST['priority'];

if(isset($_POST['doc']))
{
    $dec_of_change = $_POST['doc'];
}
if(isset($_POST['boc']))
{
    $bus_of_change = $_POST['boc'];   
}
if(isset($_POST['v1']))
{
    $variable_string1 = $_POST['v1'];       
}
if(isset($_POST['v2']))
{
    $variable_string2 = $_POST['v2'];
}
if(isset($_POST['v3']))
{
    $variable_string3 = $_POST['v3'];       
}
if(isset($_POST['v4']))
{
    $variable_string4 = $_POST['v4'];
}

if (
    $val2 == "" || 
    $val3 == "" || 
    $val4 == "" || 
    $val5 == "" || 
    $dec_of_change == "" || 
    $bus_of_change == "" || 
    $variable_string1 == "" || 
    $variable_string2 == "" || 
    $variable_string3 == ""
) {
    echo "Fill the entire form ";
    header("Location: fill.html"); 
    }

else {
    $sql="  INSERT INTO     fill1 (
                                department, date, reqby, 
                                priority, doc, boc, 
                                bpi, tu, bd, ic
                            )
            VALUES (
                                '$val2', '$val3', '$val4', 
                                '$val5', '$dec_of_change', '$bus_of_change',
                                '$variable_string1', '$variable_string2', '$variable_string3', '$variable_string4'
                            )";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    header("Location: startpage.html");

mysql_close($dbhandle);
}
```

Comment: Are you familiar with HTML, PHP, or Javascript? Your code does not indicate so (i.e. how much help do you need?). What have you tried so far?

Comment: HEy Eamonn , i am a newbie to PHP and HTMl.. i just created a sample , if its possible  for u to , just take up my code and add "addrow " functionality to html and adding multiple rows to database vai PHP ,

Comment: You can't "add addrow functionality to html". You would need to utilise Javascript for that. Not to sound too harsh, but, given the errors present in your original code I'm surprised it's working even now, without doing anything further. Your HTML tags were unclosed, there were surplus opening tags, and your PHP uses the now deprecated mysql_ syntax. I don't mean to turn you off, but I think you're putting the cart before the horse by tackling Javascript now. Concentrate on getting what you have right, then move on to dynamic tables.

Comment: i know , there a lot of errors Eamonn , i know i need to use javascript for the same , but the thing is it is workinh fine , when submit is clicked data goes to database . I would be thankful if u can rectify and please get addrows tfunctionality in my code and den to add it to database in PHP , may be its just one javascript function in HTMl code followed by a FOR or While loop in PHP

Comment: Please help me out , i need this thing to be done , Something is at stake

Answer (score 0):

If you add a button to a TD within a row you can replicate the row and add it to the table using something like:

```
// Helper function
function upTo(el, tagName) {
  el = el && el.parentNode;
  tagName = tagName.toLowerCase();

  for ( ;el; el = el.parentNode) {
    if (el.tagName && el.tagName.toLowerCase() == tagName) {
      return el;
    }
  }
  return null;
}

// Row cloning function
function cloneRow(el) {
  var newRow;
  var row = el && upTo(el, 'tr');

  if (row) {
    newRow = row.cloneNode(true);
    row.parentNode.appendChild(newRow);
  }
}
```

Note that you already have duplicate IDs in the HTML, this will create more. Duplicate names are fine.

In the table you might do:

```
<table>
  ...
  <tr>
    ...
    <td><button type="button" onclick="cloneRow(this)">Add a row</button>
  ...
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks a LOt RobG ... this gave me a sigh of relief ... very much thankful to you ....just one more thing , user enters and fills the form ...and when he submits it is supposed to go into database (check the PHP file ) , now i need a loop , to enter dynamic data into database .

Comment: but can u just tell me , when a new row is created ...like in this case a new text box is created , what will be its name , how m i supposed to access it , may for validating the entry